# Add auto-increment column on pandas multi-index

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following multi-index panda below. I am trying to create:

1. An auto-incremental counter derived from "project_rank"
2. The maximum count of projects in "lob"

However I am unsure how I would be able to do this. Any pointers would help

Raw df_matrix before:

```
print(df_matrix.head(10))
              lob          project_rank  duration_in_status
0     Commodities                CM LOB                 2.0
1     Commodities  Index Book Migration                25.0
2  Cross Platform                CM LOB                 0.0
3  Cross Platform                 CSAVA                16.0
4  Cross Platform     Calypso Migration                 0.0
5  Cross Platform       EMD / Delta One                 0.0
6  Cross Platform                  FRTB                68.0
7  Cross Platform  Index Book Migration                 1.0
8  Cross Platform           Instruments                 3.0
9  Cross Platform                 KOJAK                 0.0
```

Multi-index before:

```
                                         duration_in_status
lob            project_rank                            
Commodities    CM LOB                               2.0
               Index Book Migration                25.0
Cross Platform CM LOB                               0.0
               CSAVA                               16.0
               Calypso Migration                    0.0
               EMD / Delta One                      0.0
               FRTB                                68.0
               Index Book Migration                 1.0
               Instruments                          3.0
               KOJAK                                0.0
               LOB BOW                            324.0
               Non-Trading                          0.0
               Notes Workflow                      23.0
               PROD                                 0.0
               Result Service                      53.0
               Tech Debt                           96.0
Interest Rates LOB BOW                              0.0
Other          Notes Workflow                       0.0
Treasury       2B2                                  1.0
```

Acceptance Criteria Result:

[image]

Comment: what does the data look like before its in the multiindex?

Comment: Updated with raw data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want

```
df['proj_num'] = df.groupby('lob').project_rank.cumcount() + 1
df['depth'] = df.groupby('lob').project_rank.transform(len)
```

Before the multi-index is applied :)

```
    lob              project_rank       duration_in_status  proj_num    depth
0   Commodities      CMLOB               2.0                1           2
1   Commodities      IndexBookMigration  25.0               2           2
2   Cross_Platform   CMLOB               0.0                1           8
3   Cross_Platform   CSAVA               16.0               2           8
4   Cross_Platform   CalypsoMigration    0.0                3           8
5   Cross_Platform   EMD/DeltaOne        0.0                4           8
6   Cross_Platform   FRTB                68.0               5           8
7   Cross_Platform   IndexBookMigration  1.0                6           8
8   Cross_Platform   Instruments         3.0                7           8
9   Cross_Platform   KOJAK               0.0                8           8
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use groupby and apply.

```
# assuming "df" is the variable containing the data as you showed in the question...

import numpy as np

def group_function(sub_dataframe):
  sub_dataframe["proj_num"] = np.arange(df.shape[0]) + 1
  sub_dataframe["depth"] = df.shape[0]
  return sub_dataframe

df = df.reset_index().groupby("lob").apply(group_function)
df = df.set_index(["lob","project_rank"])
```

In case you are creating previously creating the multiindex yourself, you could do this before that. That way you wouldn't need the reset_index and could create it only once.

```
# in that case, something like this should work.
df = df.groupby("lob").apply(group_function). df.set_index(["lob","project_rank"])
```

Comment: I wouldn't. Prefer groupby, cumcount and transform for the second one.

Comment: Taking into consideration "df" I get the following exception when I run code sample above --> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index